# How can i make the div appear in same line

Tags: html, css

Please look at the jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/HE7yT/

How can i make the Image , content , Amount get displayed in the same line

If you see the picture 150 must be get displayed in same line .

```
 var HTML = $('<div class="cart" id="mee"></div>');
  var test = $("#imagesd").attr('src');
  var id_attr = $(this).attr("id");

  HTML.append('<input id_attr="'+id_attr+'" type="checkbox" checked   id= "newer" class="newer item_chk" name="item_check" value="'+$(this).attr('value')+'"/>'+$(this).attr('value')) ;
  HTML.append('<img type="img" height="40" width="40" src="'+imagesrdd+'"/>') ;
    HTML.append('<div id_attr="'+id_attr+'">'+amountdd+'</div>');
```

Please see the picture here

[image]

Comment: use floats or display inline-blocks, also your title is improper

Comment: thanks , you mean at this <div id_attr line

Comment: your comment is not understandable

Comment: I mean that this div is responsible to display the amount , so do i need to use the line styling on that div ??

Comment: HTML.append('<div id_attr="'+id_attr+'">'+amountdd+'</div>');

Comment: if you wish then use inline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make them appear in a single line then you need to use some inline element or just style them to appear inline.

You are using DIV element for + and - button, either use SPAN for them or style them with 'display: inline-block;'

```
.buttontest {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HE7yT/2/